# UITableViewDataSource can't be attach to class, compilation error in swift-ios

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, swift

Hi all today I'm practicing swift but got a strange compiler error when attach `tableViewData` source to class error message is:

> " Type 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'UITableViewDataSource'"
>    I can't add datasource.please solve this error.

```
import UIKit


class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate{



    @IBOutlet var tableview: UITableView!
     var array=["cat","dog","cow"]
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5;
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
         var Identifier:NSString="cellid"
        let cell: UITableViewCell=tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(Identifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel?.text=array[indexPath.row];

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you set the Class of your UIViewController to "ViewController" in the Storyboard (Identity Inspector on the right side)?

Comment: Check that you implement all required methods.  E.g: `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`

Comment: Default viewcontroller class is set with storyboard I checked. :(

Comment: hi sourav i'm also getting the same error with uitableviewdatasource.. how to remove that error @SouravBasuRoy

Comment: just add delegates like numberofsection,numberofitems,cellforrowindexpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    var Identifier:NSString="cellid"
    let cell: UITableViewCell=tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(Identifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text=array[indexPath.row];

    return cell
}
```

Instead of :

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
     var Identifier:NSString="cellid"
    let cell: UITableViewCell=tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(Identifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text=array[indexPath.row];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

To fix the error you must implement two methods UITableViewDataSource protocol

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```